# Special line breaking problem in my bibliography

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

The following is how my bibliography entry looks:

```
Lagrange, Joseph-Louis (1773/1775). “Recherchesd’arithmétique”. In: Œvres.Vol.3.
Hildesheim: Georg Olms Verlag, 695–795
```

The problem is: vertically, my documents ends after the "Vol.", and the 3 is not put on the next line. What can I do against that, I can't seem to figure out how to manually make it break there, since the "Vol." is not something I wrote, but placed automatically. The corresponding `biblatex` entry is

```
@book{lagrangeoevres,
  author = {Joseph-Louis Lagrange},
  title = {\OE{}vres},
  year = 1973,
  publisher = {Georg Olms Verlag},
  volume = 3,
  address = {Hildesheim}
}

@inbook{lagrange,
  author = {Joseph-Louis Lagrange},
  title = {Recherches d'arithm\'etique},
  year = {1773/1775},
  crossref = {lagrangeoevres},
  pages = "695-795"
}
```

Given these two entries in a file called ref.bib, a minimal working example should be the following, hopefully.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,url=false,doi=true,dashed=false,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\geometry{a4paper,vmargin=1.3in,left=1.6in,right=1.3in,includefoot}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{\ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get no overfull if I use the correct spelling which is “Œuvres” and not “Œvres”. See http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/

Comment: @egreg Oh, great! Thanks for remarking that, fixed it :) Must have read the name wrong when I copied it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either allow additional "emergency" space in the bibliography or change the format of the `volume` field to permit line breaks after the string "Volume"/"Vol.".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{lagrangeoevres,
  author = {Joseph-Louis Lagrange},
  title = {\OE{}vres},
  year = 1973,
  publisher = {Georg Olms Verlag},
  volume = 3,
  address = {Hildesheim}
}
@inbook{lagrange,
  author = {Joseph-Louis Lagrange},
  title = {Recherches d'arithm\'etique},
  year = {1773/1775},
  crossref = {lagrangeoevres},
  pages = "695-795"
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\textwidth=315pt% just for the example

% Variant A: Allow additional "emergency" space in the bibliography
\appto{\bibsetup}{\emergencystretch=0.5em}

% Variant B: Allow (as a last resort) line breaks after "Volume"/"Vol"
% \DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\bibstring{volume}\addhighpenspace #1}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not the best typography to divide `Vol.` and `3`.

You can use macro `\raggedright` or `\RaggedRight` (with `\usepackage{ragged2e}`). 
to get a right justified bibliography.  Change in your MWE `\printbibliography` to:

```
{\raggedright
 \printbibliography
}
```

Comment: Why not use the preamble: `\appto{\bibsetup}{\raggedright}`.

Comment: @lookstep I prefer to write it in front of `\printbibliography`. If I need to change the layout that is the first place I look.